# jquery class selector inside a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple question about the expression in jquery to select a class which involved a for loop. Basically, I have two steps: 
1. Generate some html tables with a loop.
2. Use jQuery to unhide them.

Below is the simplified code to 
1. generate html tables (I will add a loop index to separate each loop created tables) :
2. the key part of the second step is to unhide generated tables. My selector is written as: `method_options_1'+i+'`, where i is a for loop index.

```
for (var i = 2; i <= 5; i++) {
  <tr class="method_options_1'+i+'" style="display: none;"><th><label for="id_CAM_1">Chemical application Method (CAM):</label></th>
      <td><select name="CAM_1_'+i+'" id="id_1_'+i+'">
        <option value="2">2-Interception based on crop canopy</option>
        <option value="9">9-Linear foliar based on crop canop</option></select>
      </td></tr>

  $('.method_options_1'+i).closest('tr').show();  
}
```

However, this selector does not work, which means I could not show the hidden element. While, if I remove the index i from both the HTML and jquery, the selector works. Since I have to keep the i index, can anyone give me some suggestions (I tried to remove closest('tr'), but it does not work)?

Comment: Where is that html from? It is from a program code which construct the html?

Comment: I will use jquery to generate html on the fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'.method_options_1'+i` is already a `tr`, so first try removing the `closest('tr')` step:

```
$('.method_options_1'+i).show();
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/WJDCm/

Comment: thanks for the reply. I tried to remove the closest('tr'), but it does not work

Comment: Thanks for your help. I know your code should work, but somehow my just does not work. I need to re-exam it

Answer (score 0):

That's because as far as Javascript is concerned, `name` is simply a string: `method_options_1'+i'`. It does not evaluate any code inside that string. If you want to do it correctly, do something like this:

HTML:

`<tr class="method_options">etc</tr>`

Javascript:

`$('.method_options:eq('+i+')').show();`

**EDIT:**

Perhaps I misunderstood. You are generating this inside a Javascript `for` loop, so `i` is a valid variable in code space. If that's the case, then you simply have to take out `closest()`, as it tells jQuery to travel up the DOM and select the first `tr` that it finds. In this case, that appears to be nothing. You want to work on the `tr` that you selected, not a `tr` that is a parent of the one you are selecting.

Answer (score 0):

I really wonder how you run the above code... however doing this does work

HTML:

```
 ​<table id='myTable'>
 </table>​​​​​​​​
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function(){

  for (var i = 2; i <= 5; i++) {
     $('#myTable').append('<tr class="method_options_1'+i+'" style="display: none;"><th><label for="id_CAM_1">Chemical application Method (CAM):</label></th><td><select name="CAM_1_'+i+'" id="id_1_'+i+'">        <option value="2">2-Interception based on crop canopy</option>        <option value="9">9-Linear foliar based on crop canop</option></select>      </td></tr>');


     $('.method_options_1'+i).closest('tr').toggle('slow');   
  }


})
```

[Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/5NZPL/1/)